# Шапка сайта на bootsrap

Tags: css3, html5, bootstrap

сейчас занимаюсь версткой сайта на bootstrap3.3.7 и у меня проблема с шапкой,на мобильной версии она сама открывается,я не знаю,как это решить

```
<head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Atoda</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/be283c36b0.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
                    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/media.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse">
                        <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
                    </button>
                    <a href="index.html" class="navbar-brand">Atoda</a>
                </div>
                <div id="navbar-collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li class="active"><a href="">Главная</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#about">О нас</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#portfolio">Вы получите</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Замени

```
<div id="navbar-collapse">
```

на

```
<div id="navbar-collapse" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
```

и убери строку (два раза bootsrap подгружается .min и обычный)

```
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```